# Lebesgue Integral over vanishing interval

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $f(x)$ be a Lebesgue integrable function. Then is it true that 
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^\epsilon f(x)\,dx=0
$$
always? When $f(x)$ is bounded answer is trivial, but if we wish to show this for unbounded functions, how would one proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is integrable, then this follows from either the monotone or dominated convergence theorems, with dominating function $|f|$.